# I'm trying to remove the background from an image (using inkscape)

Tags: inkscape, editing

I'm trying to create infographs - how can I remove the background of a photo? If (for instance) it was a photo of Obama - how would I go about modifying the photo so it was just his head and torso?

Comment: Not sure what you have in mind, but Gimp seems more appropriate.

Comment: Inkscape is best suited to vector graphics. A photo is raster/bitmap data. The task you seem to have in mind is achieved much easier in a bitmap manipulation program like e.g. Gimp, as Jacob already suggested.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to use gimp to do this and when you have the image you can use it on Inkscape to do your infographic.

You can install gimp from a terminal:
*sudo apt-get install gimp*

or from ubuntu software center.

[Here is a tutorial to do what you want to do on gimp](http://www.photo-info.co.nz/articles/removing-image-backgrounds-gimp)
and 
[Here is a tutorial to do it on Inkscape](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jx033xneaT4)

If you have questions about gimp or inkscape you should probably visit their sites: 
gimp.org
inkscape.org
where you can find plenty of tutorials